# endless import: "sbt: extracting project structure from sbt" - SCALA project

Tags: java, scala, sbt, intellij-plugin

I have a problem with my scala project.
I try to create a new project with SBT builder but once I create it I am stuck with this message:
**sbt: extracting project structure from sbt**

I use:
sbt 1.8.0,
scala 2.13.10,
Intellij 2022.2.3,
SDT 1.8/11/17/19

I will be really grateful if someone has any idea how can I solve it.

[image: communicate]

[image: SBT shell]

I tired to use different version of SBT, scala, JDK, installing/uninstalling ItelliJ, removing sbt.boot.lock or importing external sources of sbt and scala. Nothing works.

Comment: Can you build your project without IntelliJ (outside IntelliJ)? `sbt clean compile`

Comment: @DmytroMitin I did it and I'm stuck with this message: "getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.8.0  (this may take some time)...". I waited for 30 minutes approx

Comment: There was a problem with IntelliJ that two different IntelliJ sbt processes or one outside Intellij and one inside can hang https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-18626/SBT-locks-forever-waiting-for-.sbt-idea-lock@for  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7355 But if you experience difficulties without IntelliJ (and restarting/killing the process doesn't help) this can be also some connectivity issue. Are you behind proxy?

Comment: I don't use proxy at all. I tried to play with different projects at the same time to detect some concurrencies, but nothing works.

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/discussions/14979